# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DataFrame' analisis sentiment python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, twitter, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm having problems, I'm doing a sentiment analysis exercise. My dataframe is called Tweet

```
def cleanText(text):
  text = text.lower()
  # Removes all mentions (@username) from the tweet since it is of no use to us
  text = re.sub(r'(@[A-Za-z0-9_]+)', '', text)
    
  # Removes any link in the text
  text = re.sub('http://\S+|https://\S+', '', text)

  # Only considers the part of the string with char between a to z or digits and whitespace characters
  # Basically removes punctuation
  text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', text)

  # Removes stop words that have no use in sentiment analysis 
  text_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
  text = [word for word in text_tokens if not word in stopwords.words()]

  text = ' '.join(text)
  return text
```

```
def stem(text):
  # This function is used to stem the given sentence
  porter = PorterStemmer()
  token_words = word_tokenize(text)
  stem_sentence = []
  for word in token_words:
    stem_sentence.append(porter.stem(word))
  return " ".join(stem_sentence)
```

definition of feelings

```
def sentiment(cleaned_text):
  if cleaned_text.sentiment.polarity > 0:
    return 'positive'
  elif cleaned_text.sentiment.polarity < 0:
    return 'negative'
  else:
    return 'neutral'
```

this is where the error appears

`tweet2 = tweet.DataFrame(text, columns= ['full_text', 'clean_tweets','sentiment'])`

```
tweet2 = tweet.DataFrame(text, columns= ['full_text', 'clean_tweets','sentiment'])
```

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-df4fc28e4af3> in <module>()
----> 1 tweet2 = tweet.DataFrame(text, columns= ['full_text', 'clean_tweets','sentiment'])

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5139             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5140                 return self[name]
-> 5141             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5142 
   5143     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

Comment: What is `tweet` on your code?

Comment: Twitter = list (collection.find())   ; tweet = pd.DataFrame(Twitter), I ingest the information in Mongo DB, first the query is done by list and then by a dataframe that I create . The result of the variables fulltext ',' clean tweets ',' sentiment; The first answer appears as previously I converted it to string, the sentiment column and clean_tweets the result is NaN